# firestore emulator has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm running

`firebase emulators:start`

and getting

`firestore emulator has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT`

[image]

[image]

## edited

[image]

---

## As Clarity suggested in the comments section

### [image]

## firestore-debug.log

[image]

Comment: If you find a reproducible problem with the Firebas CLI, please post an issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson... the problem I was trying to solve with the firebase function I was able to solve with client side code ... so I didn´t continued to test the issue... for the moment... :thumbsup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had this issue and i just fixed it, install firebase tools like so:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

and then log into the firebase project like this:

```
firebase login -p <PROJECT_NAME>
```

and it would work

Comment: `npm install -g firebase-tools` It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error message, you need to setup your emulator first:

```
firebase setup:emulators:firestore
```

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup

Comment: I´ve done that twice ... but still... I´ve edited the question .. to add the print screen showing the console when I´ve done the firestore emulator setup... but still, I´ll check the docs ref you´ve sent

Comment: What if you start firestore only? `firebase serve --only firestore`

Comment: I´ve edited once again the question in response of your question... still giving a error message

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well the only solution, I've discovered to this is to run that same command `firebase emulators:start` again and again and again. Until it works. Works for me every time. Hilariously!!! yes.

I don't know what really happens under the hood but, That's just a hacky way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
Finally it worked through making this request before starting the emulators again :

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```